# Chrome pop up instead of login page after wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

So I installed wordpress (in a subfolder if it matters). After the installation I want to log in to my admin page (by going to /wp-login.php).

Instead of the login page, as I would expect it, I get the Chrome login pop-up. The login data with which I installed Wordpress does not work.

[image: Browser login pop up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inquired the server admin and he suggested that I use **wpadmin** as an username and password. It worked. After I did that I got the normal Wordpress user page. The password is set by the admin to prevent brute-force attacks. If one has the same problem, just ask your admin for password (mine was wpadmin). @Tim Malone

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly surmised, this is not the Wordpress login screen.

This login is popping up because password protection is set up on the folder that you installed Wordpress in.

It depends on your server setup, but most likely this is being controlled from a file on your server called `.htaccess`. You will probably find it inside the subfolder you installed in, or possibly in the root folder of the site.

If you open that file and look for lines similar to the following, removing them will remove the password protection, and let you log in to Wordpress as usual.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Although - you might want to find out who added it there and why they added it, before removing it!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. There was indeed a .htaccess file in the wordpress folder, but it contained only some code made by the wordpress itself. Removing it did not chanhe anything.

Comment: @drzamich That's fine, that's the standard WordPress .htaccess code. So there's no .htacess in the /m5 folder?

Comment: There is no other .htaccces file on my server. There is though a .htpasswd folder outside the public_html folder, which contains only a .protected.list file, which is empty.

Comment: @drzamich That's most likely linked to this. Do you have cPanel on your server by any chance? If you do, log in there (the address will be `http://example.com:2082/`, obviously replace example.com with your domain) and go to Password Protected Directories - is there a listing in there?

Comment: After the mailing with the admin, I got the answer: to prevent brute-force attack, the server requires double authentication on wp-login.php file.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Glad you solved it :) Seems like a decent idea, although using the simple username/password you mentioned in your answer doesn't seem like it would help much!

Comment: it's something :) Thank you for your involvement.

Answer (score 2):

add below code in .htaccess file
**Satisfy Any**

Comment: This works for me!